# selenium span link li not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium. I am practicing to write a test case on http://www.countdown.tfl.gov.uk. Below are the steps I followed:

- a) I opened the browser to selenium Web Driver
- b) Found the search text Box  and enter H32 and clicked on search button to selenium.

Till this part it works fine.

Now on the page I am actually getting two records on the left side of the page under the search. I am actually trying to click on the first one i.e. "Towards Southall,Townhall" link. Nothing is happening.

Below is my code:

```java
 public class CountdownTest {   
        @Test
        public void tflpageOpen(){
            WebDriver driver = openWebDriver();
            searchforBus(driver,"H32");
                selectrouteDirection(driver)

        }

    //open the countdowntfl page
        private WebDriver openWebDriver(){
            WebDriver driver = WebDriverFactory.getWebDriver("FireFox");
            driver.get("http://www.countdown.tfl.gov.uk");
            return driver;

        }
        private void searchforBus(WebDriver driver,String search){
            WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='initialSearchField']"));
            searchBox.sendKeys(search);
            WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='ext-gen35']"));
            searchButton.click();

        }
        private void selectrouteDirection(WebDriver driver){
            WebElement towardssouthallLink= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='ext-gen165']']"));
            ((WebElement) towardssouthallLink).click();

        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting `NoSuchElement Exception` now, you may try the following code with the usage of [WebDriver explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits).

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
WebElement towardssouthallLink = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//*[@id='route-search']//li/span)[1]")));
towardssouthallLink.click();
```

Or [WebDriver implicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)

```java
WebDriver driver = WebDriverFactory.getWebDriver("FireFox");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.countdown.tfl.gov.uk");
```

Tips:

- The search results need some time to be retrieved, so please use `Explicit wait` or `Implicit wait`.
- Don't use locators like `span[@id='ext-gen165']`, they are ExtJs auto generated.
- In this case, css selector can also be used: `#route-search li:nth-of-type(1) > span`

Comment: Yes, Few Things I learn today those explicit wait and how to handle ExtJS in Selenium. This is really great time for me Hurrey......

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling `selectrouteDirection`.

You probably want:

```
@Test
public void tflpageOpen(){
    WebDriver driver = openWebDriver();
    searchforBus(driver,"H32");
    selectrouteDirection(driver);
}
```

You also don't need to cast here:

```
((WebElement) towardssouthallLink).click();
```

It's already a `WebElement` anyway.

Comment: @user1177636, happens to me all the time! No worries!

Comment: Ya, That is really silly Mistake, But after calling that method also it is not working. It is throwing an Exception as NoSuchElement Exception

Comment: @user1519005, that is an entirely different problem, and one of the other guys answers should help. Essentially they are very much correct in that the elements are given dynamic ID's, thus your original XPath will probably fail most times and work others.

Answer (score 0):

I found that id for those links are dynamically generated. ids are of the form 'ext-genXXX' where XXX is number which is dynamically generated hence varies each time.

Actually, you should try with linkText:

For 'Towards Southall, Town Hall'

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Towards Southall, Town Hall")).click
```

For 'Towards Hounslow, Bus Station'

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Towards Hounslow, Bus Station")).click
```

Here is a logic:
Get all elements which have id starts with 'ext-gen' & iterate over it & click on link with matching text. Following is Ruby code(sorry, I don't know Java well):

```
links = driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//span[starts-with(@id, 'ext-gen')]")

links.each do |link|
   if link.text == "Towards Southall, Town Hall"
     link.click
     break
   end
end
```

Comment: Please see my above answer, edited with Ruby code. It worked for me!

Comment: @user1177636 both links have same class name. Still you want to use it.

Comment: Actually, they are two different issues here. One is using `linkText` or xpath/css selector with class names, the other one is use `id` or xpath/css selector with class names for ExtJs. For the first one, `linkText` is fine in most of the cases, but not a good practice if it can be avoided (in this particular case, it's fine). The second issue is for ExtJs, using `id` like `//span[starts-with(@id, 'ext-gen')]` should be avoided no matter what.

Comment: @grm, Yes you are right, Now I can see that. I will try this and let you know the result.

Comment: @user1177636 ,I agree with what you say , as not to depend on "//span[starts-with(@id, 'ext-gen')]" what I feel is if there are many number of elements starts with the Id then there will some bit performance and Object Memory also increase, am I right.